# Find the process id of the process name

Tags: unix

I know to find the process id of the process name using the top, pidof, ps commands.
Anyother way to find the process id of the process name. Thanks in Advance.

For example:

```
        pidof bash 
        4587
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for [**`pgrep`**](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?pgrep+1)

```
pgrep bash
```

---

Another option

```
ps -ef | grep sshd | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: @Kalanidhi Aren't these two more than sufficient? Sorry to say but I am not aware of any other alternative.

Comment: I have used those ps, pidof, top. You said pgrep it was also helpful but i am searching for another commands like that. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this:

```
ps -A | grep 'process_name'
```

You can refer: [ps command](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-ps-command/) for more information